# How to force Mac to recognise USB drive

Tags: usb

During my app development/testing cycle, I'm frequently re-connecting my Garmin watch as a USB drive to my Mac, and am frustrated having to wait for the sometimes 30+ seconds before the Mac automatically recognises the new connection.

Is there any way to force the Mac to re-establish the connection? Catalina 10.15.6

Comment: Do you actually eject the watch when you are done?  I've seen similar delays with usb sticks where I've pulled them out and the OS has effectively run a disk check on them when I put them in...

Comment: Sometimes I do, sometimes not. It makes no difference, every reconnection takes at least 30 sec's.There's nothing that I can see that would indicate it's doing a disk check when I reconnect.

Comment: And it's not the watch: I have a number of watches, and they all display the same delay in reconnecting.